# Flutter - Merge video and widgets

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I have a screen with a video as background and I can add text, images (gif or not), emojis, etc.. over it. I can already generate images from Widgets which will work well for non gifs images.

All right it is working quite right, but now I need to compile all into a single video. Someone can tell me what is the easyest way to do that?

Ps.: There's this package, but I'm not sure if it is what I need for it.
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, this package will do the work, but is very complex and request a lot of time studying it, have fun =)

Comment: if you can put some code that helped you it will be better and considered as answer

Comment: I did everything using the ffmpeg, and that's right, I took a lot of hours studying this, it's not that easy to achieve the goals with ffmpeg, but it's possible. @NeelaySrivastava I did not requested any code with my question, that time I was only searching for the best tool to do that.

Comment: look your question i going to help more ppl if future i know the hard ship you went through i also know the pain and effort but buy putting a question and accepting the answer you are also making a path toward the solution so if you can put more context it will be great . I am not saying to put code just the path toward the solution.

Comment: @NeelaySrivastava The FFmpeg library is powerful and has a LOT of features, to do so you'll need to study it and adapt it to your reality. Here, I'm using the FFmpeg to get a video or picture from user (by device gallery or camera) and compiling somehow. Go to http://ffmpeg.org/ and good luck.